# This operation can be performed only on a computer that is joined to a server farm by users who have permissions in SQL Server

Tags: sharepoint-server, central-administration

This operation can be performed only on a computer that is joined to a server farm by users who have permissions in SQL Server to read from the configuration database.

I get this error while accessing central admin after server reboot in production.

Checked SQL services - running;
checked permission for farm account in databases - sys admin in sql server;
password for farm account is never expiring;
no default gateway change in web server;
firewall disabled

Answer (score 0):

finally resolved issue with help from 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0d551321-7586-435a-b744-4e1e4cb4801b/sharepoint-2013-runtime-error-server-error-in-application?forum=sharepointgeneral

"I resolved this exact issue. This is a .net issue. I found a warning in the Event Viewer Event Code: 3005. To fix this issue I opened regedit and under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework I created a new registry DWORD called LoaderOptimization. I gave it a value of 1 then did an IIS Reset. This resolved the issue."

.but wanted to know the reason why this worked.